# Creating MapView without XAML

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I try to create MapView without XAML but I can't. My code blocks in below

```
class ShowMap : ContentPage
{
    public ShowMap()
    {
        Title = "Show a Map";

        Map myMap = new Map(Basemap.CreateImagery());
        MapView MyMapView = new MapView();
        MyMapView.Map = myMap;



        //Content = new StackLayout
        //{
        //    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        //    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        //    Children =
        //    {
        //        MyMapView
        //    }
        //};

    }
}
```

If I uncomment block in code. Shown an error.

```
cannot convert from 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Controls.MapView' to 'Xamarin.Forms.View'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you are trying to use the 'native' MapView on Xamarin forms. Make sure that the [MapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/android/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Xamarin_Forms_MapView.htm) is type of Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms.MapView.